# Pass data to modal component on vueJS

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal, frontend, vuejs2

What's the best way to pass the title `{{post.name}}` and image `post.imgAttribution` from tile-component to modal-component so both elements display the same data when the button is pressed?

```
<div id="root" class= "container">
    <hero-component></hero-component>
    <div class="tile is-ancestor">
        <tile-component  v-for="post in posts" :key="post.id">
            <template slot="header-title">{{post.name}}</template>
            <template slot="content-photo"><img :src= "post.imgAttribution"/> </template>
            <template slot="button-modal">
                <modal-component v-show="showModal" @close="showModal = false"></modal-component>
                <a class="button is-primary" v-on:click="showModal=true">Show Cat</a>
            </template>
        </tile-component>   
    </div>
</div>
```

components:

```
var HeroComponent = Vue.component('hero-component', {
template: `
        <div>
            <section class="hero">
                      <div class="hero-body">
                        <div class="container">
                          <h1 class="title">
                            Cat Gallery
                          </h1>
                        </div>
                      </div>
            </section>
        </div>`});

    var TileComponent = Vue.component('tile-component', {
        template:`
        <div>
              <div class="tile is-parent">
                <article class="tile is-child box">
                    <p class="title">
                    <slot name="header-title"></slot>
                </p>
                <p class="content-photo">
                    <slot name="content-photo"></slot>
                </p>
                    <slot name="button-modal"></slot>
            </article>  
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>`});

    var ModalComponent = Vue.component('modal', {
    template: `
    <div>
        <div class="modal is-active">
            <div class="modal-background"></div>
                <div class="modal-card">
                    <header class="modal-card-head">
                        <p class="modal-card-title">
                            <!-- title from tile-component -!>
                        </p>
                    <button class="modal-close" @click="$emit('close')" ></button>
                    </header>
                    <section class="modal-card-body">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <p class="image is-4by3">
                                <!-- image from tile-component -!></p>
                        </div>
                    </section>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>`});

    Vue.component('modal-component', ModalComponent);

    new Vue({   
        el: '#root',
        data: {
            showModal: false,
            posts: [],
            errors: []
        },
        component: {
            'hero-component': HeroComponent,
            'modal-component': ModalComponent,
            'tile-component': TileComponent
        },
        created() {
            axios.get('http://localhost:3000/Cat/')
            .then(response => this.posts = response.data)
            .catch(e => this.error.push(e));
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You're already using slots, why not continue?

```
var ModalComponent = Vue.component('modal', {
    template: `
      <div>
        <div class="modal is-active">
          <div class="modal-background"></div>
          <div class="modal-card">
            <header class="modal-card-head">
              <p class="modal-card-title">
                <slot name="title"></slot>
              </p>
              <button class="modal-close" @click="$emit('close')" ></button>
            </header>
            <section class="modal-card-body">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <p class="image is-4by3">
                  <slot name="image"></slot>
                </p>
              </div>
            </section>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
`});
```

And pass the values this way. Here I'm using a header and an img element, but you could do what you want.

```
<modal-component v-show="showModal" @close="showModal = false">
    <h1 slot="title">{{post.name}}</h1>
    <img slot="image" :src="post.imgAttribution" alt="" />
</modal-component>
```

Comment: Great it works well, thanks! The issue now is that modal-component it only displays the last item in the posts. Did you have a clue to fix that?

Comment: @Manoxs its not that the last one is shown, its that *all* are shown. All your modals work off one value, `showModal`. Here's one way you might get around that. https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/xdeGmy?editors=1010